# Ruby on Rails Routes Clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm not completely new to Ruby on Rails but it is not my most proficient framework so I was hoping someone could help me wrap my head around some code I'm trying to understand.

controller:

```
def new
    @biz = Business.new
end

def apply
    @biz = Business.new(business_params)
    token = SecureRandom.hex(4)
    @biz.verify_token = token
    if @biz.save
        message = @biz.sentMessages.new
        message.send_verify_email
        redirect_to waiting_verification_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

routes:

```
get 'apply', to: 'businesses#new', as: 'apply'
post 'apply', to: 'businesses#apply', as: 'applied'
```

view:

```
= simple_form_for @biz, url: apply_path, html: {autocomplete: "off"} do |f|
```

I understand that the first line of the routes directs a request at `/apply` to the `new` action in the controller which creates a new business object and renders the `new` view, which I have included a snippet from. This snippet includes the form action which directs a successful submission to the `apply_path`.

My understanding indicates that this `apply_path` is a named helper for the first routes line when I believe it should be directed to the second line, whose helper would be `applied_path`, and would then be handled by the `apply` action on the controller.

What is really causing me confusion is that this functionality works. So the submission is in fact being routed to the second routes line and being handled by the `apply` action in the controller. If you could explain how this is happening I would appreciate it tremendously. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
= simple_form_for @bix, url: apply_path
```

generates something like

```
<form action="/apply" method="post">
  .. 
</form>
```

POST is the default method on forms, so when the form is then `POST-ed` Rails looks at the routes.rb file and sees a match on this line.

```
post 'apply', to: 'businesses#apply', as: 'applied'
```

If however you had done it like this

```
= simple_form_for @bix, url: apply_path, method: :get
```

The form is submitted via `GET` and then Rails would find a match on the first line in routes.rb.

```
get 'apply', to: 'businesses#new', as: 'apply'
```

It doesn't matter what the name of the routes_helpers are, all that matters is the generated url. I hope that clears thing out, if not, just ask for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The generated form will look like

```html
<form action="/apply" method="post" autocomplete="off" class="simple_form new_business">
```

Note the `method` attribute: Because `@biz` is a new record, SimpleForm knows this should be HTTP POST'ed to the `url` specified (AFAIK persisted records will still create a `method="post"` on the form, but an additional hidden field with `name="_method"` and `value="put"` is inserted).

Since both route helpers, `apply_path` and `applied_path`, just generate the string `'/apply'`, it does not matter which URL you define in your form. This should equally well work:

```
= simple_form_for @biz, url: applied_path, html: {autocomplete: "off"} do |f|
```

---

When you submit the form, your browser creates an HTTP request, like this:

```
POST /apply HTTP/1.1
<header information>

<post body>
```

and [Journey](https://github.com/rails/journey) (the Rails router module) will take the information `POST` + `/apply` to find the route to `businesses#apply`.

---

To make the route definition a little more concise, you could rewrite it as

```
scope as: :apply do
  get  '/apply', to: 'businesses#new'
  post '/apply', to: 'businesses#apply'
end
```

Comment: I should add, that path helpers not *only* or *simply* generate strings, but generate URLs based on the information in the route definition. That is, things like adding formats (`apply_path(format: :json)`→`/apply.json`), adding protocol/host/port (`apply_url`→`http://example.com/apply`), parameter interpolation (e.g. `users_path(@user)`→`/users/42`), etc. In the end, they will output a string though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is working is that you have two named routes that map to the same path.  `applied_path` is `/apply`, and `apply_path` is `/apply`.  These two named paths are IDENTICAL.  The difference comes when the form performs a `POST` to `/apply`, it sees a `POST` and immediately goes to the second route.  While a `GET` to that same `/apply` path will go to the first route.

On this note, you only really need to name one of the routes and just use that name everywhere.  This is why, when you declare a resource in your routes file:

```
resources :users
```

You end up with a "POST /users" and a "GET /users" path which routes to `users#create` and `users#index` respectively, based on what kind of request was sent - BUT you only have one `users_path` named route, which always returns "/users"